# Google maps api v3 waypoints not showing on the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm working on a google maps v3 project and i've come to a point where i need some help. I have a google map where the user can enter a start and end points, which works fine but when i want to enter waypoints for some reason they wont work( up to 8 waypoints ). Could someone look at the code and help me?
This is how far i have come with the project:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link href="map_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="maps.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
//-->
</script>

</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="total"></div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="control_panel">
        <div id="user_input">

            <label for="start">Start :</label>
              <input type="text" id="start" name="start" /><br />

            <i>Add multiple Stops along the route (Optional)</i><br />
            <ul id="stops">
               <li>
                <label for="stop1">Stop 1:</label>
                <input type="text" id="stop1" name="stop1" />
                </li>
            </ul>
            <input type="button" id="addScnt" value="Add Stop" /><br />

            <label for="end">End :</label>
              <input type="text" id="end" name="end" /><br />
            <br />
              <input type="submit" value="Create Route" onclick="calcRoute();" />
              <input type="button" id="button" value="Show/Hide Directions" onclick="toggle_visibility('directions_panel');" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="directions_panel"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my js file:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

  var scntUl = $('#stops');
  var ii = $('#stops').size() + 1;
 var MaxInputs = 8;

$('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
    if (ii <= MaxInputs) {

    $('<li><label for="stop' + ii +'">Stop ' + ii + ': </label><input type="text" id="stop' + ii +'" name="stop' + ii + '" /><input type="button" id="remScnt" value="X" /></li>').appendTo(scntUl);
    ii++;
    }
    return false;
});

$('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
    if (ii > 2) {
        $(this).parents('li').remove();
        ii--;
    }
    return false;
 });
}); 

 var directionDisplay;
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 var map;

 function initialize() {
 directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
 var map = new google.maps.LatLng(37.09, -95.71);
 var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  center: map
 }
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("directions_panel"));

 }

 function calcRoute() {
 var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
 var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
var waypts = [];
    for (var ii = 0; ii < thisStop; ii++) {      
        var thisStop = document.getElementById("stop" + (ii+1)).value;
        if (thisStop.length > 0) {
            if (thisStop.length > 0) {
                waypts[ii] = {location: thisStop};
            }
        }
    }   

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: false,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
        summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
    }
      computeTotalDistance(response);
    }); 
}

    function computeTotalDistance(result) {
        var totalDist = 0;
        var totalTime = 0;
        var myroute = result.routes[0];
            for (i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
                totalDist += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
                totalTime += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;      
            }
        var miles = 0.000621371192;

        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = ("Total distance is: "+ (Math.round( totalDist * miles * 10 ) / 10 ) + " miles " + " and " + " Approximate time is: " + (totalTime / 60 / 60).toFixed(1) + " hours.");
    }
```

If someone needs more info please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot of code to look at. Can you put up a test page, or even a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

In the meantime, I do see a problem here:

```
var scntUl = $('#stops');
var ii = $('#stops').size() + 1;
```

`$('#stops')` gives you a jQuery object for the `<ul id="stops">` element itself, not its children. The `length` of this object will be 1 no matter how many `<li>` elements you add inside it. Perhaps you want `$('#stops>li')` instead? That will give you a jQuery object containing all of the `<li>` elements.

(BTW you can use the `.length` property instead of the `.size()` method - the method is there only for compatibility with old code.)

Also, why are you adding 1 to that length? I didn't look at the code much beyond that, but if you want the number of `<li>` elements you would just take `.length` as it is.

I also noticed that the `<input>` elements all have `id="remScnt"`. You shouldn't use an `id` more than once; use a `class` or generate unique ids (or both).

One other thing - `.live()` is deprecated; use `.on` instead.

Updated after you posted the map link...

Take a look at this code:

```
for (var ii = 0; ii < thisStop; ii++) {      
    var thisStop = document.getElementById("stop" + (ii+1)).value;
    if (thisStop.length > 0) {
        if (thisStop.length > 0) {
            waypts[ii] = {location: thisStop};
        }
    }
}
```

There are at least three or four problems here. But rather than try to fix this code as it is, why not take advantage of jQuery to make it easier?

First, go back to the code in your `#addScnt` click handler where it appends each new `<li>` into the DOM, and add a classname to the `<input>` tag, e.g.

```
<input class="waypoint" ...and the existing attributes here... />
```

And then where you have that loop above, change it to:

```
var waypts = [];
$('.waypoint').each( function( i, input ) {
    var value = $(input).val();
    if( value.length ) waypts.push({ location: value });
});
```

Note that this code no longer depends on the inputs having the IDs `stop1`, `stop2`, etc. Unless you need those IDs elsewhere, you can remove them.

Also I noticed you still have this code:

```
var scntUl = $('#stops>li');
var ii = $('#stops').length;
```

What do you think the value of `ii` will be here? Also, later you have this:

```
$('<li>...</li>').appendTo(scntUl);
```

That can't be right. Shouldn't this be appending to `#stops` itself? You're nesting `<li>` elements now, which is not what you intended.

Finally, use the Developer Tools in Chrome or another browser to troubleshoot these problems. SO is a great resource, of course, and questions here are always welcome. But it's even better when you can troubleshoot the problems you run into **right now** with the Developer Tools in Chrome or other browsers. It's worth spending some time exploring all the options available there. [Start here for a tutorial on the Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: hey Michael, i was away sorry. if you go to [link](http://www.motorcycleavenue.com), you will see the map. Thank you for your help.

Comment: the reason why i want the ids incremented is because that's how i have the waypoints working.

Comment: the map is at this [link](http://motorcycleavenue.com). if anyone would like to help. Thank you

Comment: thank you Michael very much for all your help. i still need a lot of learning and that is the reason my code is not correct. i'll look into dev tools.

Comment: Hey, we all need a lot of learning, myself included! My code is usually not correct when I first write it either. :-) And I didn't mean to give the wrong impression with my latest comment: Stack Overflow is a great resource, so don't hesitate to ask questions here. But the developer tools sure are great for tracking problems down, investigating how a page works, etc.

Comment: i just wish i knew more people that like coding and maybe meet with them once a month or so and learn more from each other. everything i know so far i thought myself reading books. Thank you again for all the support and help.

Comment: Well, you're doing great so far. I wonder if there is a JavaScript/web developer user group in your area? One place to check would be on [Meetup](http://www.meetup.com/) - type JavaScript into their search box for example.

Comment: My project is not ready yet, i still have some work to do. May i contact you private for some general questions or to guide me with my project, if it is ok with you? Thank you, Michael.